# How can I configure TestStack.White timeouts?

Tags: configuration, timeout, white-framework

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 and I got `TestStack.White` via `NuGet` (I got version `0.10.3.118`).

Problem is, my test clicks a button which triggers an action that exceeds the default 5 second timeout. So my test always yields:

```
[Error] 'White.Core.Interceptors.CoreInterceptor' Error when invoking Click, on Button with parameters: 

White.Core.UIItems.UIActionException : Window didn't respond, after waiting for 5000 ms
  ----> System.Exception : Timeout occured, after waiting for 5000 ms
```

I read [White's doc about waiting](https://github.com/TestStack/White/wiki/Waiting), but it says to look at Configuration section to see how to set my own timeout values. And that section does not exist.

**Update**: I tried creating a file called `TestStack.White.dll.config` and placed it in the same directory as `TestStackWhite.dll` and my test dll. The contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>

    <sectionGroup name="White">
      <section name="Core" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler"/>
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

  <White>
    <Core>
      <add key="WorkSessionLocation" value="." />
      <add key="PopupTimeout" value="5000" />
      <add key="SuggestionListTimeout" value="10000" />
      <add key="BusyTimeout" value="10000" />
      <add key="WaitBasedOnHourGlass" value="true" />
      <add key="UIAutomationZeroWindowBugTimeout" value="10000" />
      <add key="TooltipWaitTime" value="10000" />
      <add key="DragStepCount" value="4" />
    </Core>
  </White>
</configuration>
```

Nevertheless, I'm still getting the 5 seconds timeout whether I run my test from inside NUnit or VS + Resharper...

Comment: It's March 2017 and I found this section about Teststack.White and "waiting": http://teststackwhite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/AdvancedTopics/Waiting/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

These timeouts can be configured programmatically, in your test code. For example:

```
CoreAppXmlConfiguration.Instance.BusyTimeout = 20000;
```

To do it using an `App.Config`, such file must be associated to the test assembly. So adding an `App.Config` to my test project and pasting the content from the question works as well.

Answer (score 1):

I solved a problem like yours, where the the test timeout when I click on element. I've used this:

```
  Mouse.Instance.Location = element.ClickablePoint;
  Mouse.Instance.Click();
```

Comment: Thanks this truly solves error "
TestStack.White.UIItems.UIActionException: 'Window didn't respond, after waiting for {0} ms' on Button.Click()

Comment: After I answer this, I found this way too:
Mouse.Instance.Click(item.ClickablePoint);